Pakistani having uk visa.entry in UAE
As a Pakistani citizen can i get a visa on arrival in Dubai on a valid uk visa? please guide.

No.
The only exceptions of this sort exist for Indian citizens, who can get a UAE Visa on Arrival if they have one of several documents, but even for them UK visitor visa is not one of them, they need a UK residence visa (other suitable documents are currently: US Visitor Visa, US Green Card, EU Residence Permit/Visa). (source from official UAE govt website)
As a Pakistan citizen you will need to get a visa, depending on your airline you may be able to get a "prearranged visa", applying and paying online thru the airline's website. As a Pakistan citizen you will also need your National ID card alongside your passport. More info here on emirates website.

thanks your answer was helpful.

@YousufDaud please mark it as answer if it answered your question.
